# Подключаемый com объект и IntelliSense

Tags: c#, intellisense

Есть com объект, написанный на delphi в виде dll. Подключаю его в проект через Add Reference..->Browse. Но не могу посмотреть по ссылке ни Object Browser, ни добавить на него в класс using (подсвечивается красным). Что я делаю не так и как мне исправить положение (если возможно)?

Comment: А добавление происходит успешно?

Comment: да, без всяких проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, перед добавлением ссылки в проект нужно добавить com-объект в регистр windows c помощью программы regsvr32 - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb4909... . После этого добавлять ссылку через Add Reference -> COM

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747 и здесь некоторые нюансы о работе regsvr32, о которых не стоит забывать.